# Gigya with ADFS as SAML IdP - How to add groups to Gigya Account

Tags: adfs, gigya

I am using ADFS as SAML IdP for Gigya. I have setup the integration in both ways, SAML Login is working fine and able to create an account in Gigya. How do I save the Groups in Gigya as Arrays? I am getting AD groups as array in the SAML response from ADFS. I have tried adding the groups by setting Attribute Map as Gigya field as array as described under Gigya documentation but it is not setting the group info in Gigya!

Any help is higlhy appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The attribute mapping in Gigya's console must be into the "samlData" object (of the profile), like so:
IdP Attribute Name: some-name (as written in the saml xml response)
CDC/Gigya Field Name: samlData.x[] (The brackets are mandatory)